# FK collection returned by EF is null, but validation for duplicates, confirms thats, the collection has content

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get a data of all the user drone's, but ef core returning empty collection.

```
public class User : AuditableEntity
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string UserData { get; set; }
       public bool IsActive { get; set; }
       public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
       public DateTime LastActivity { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Drone> Drones { get; set; }
   }
public class Drone : AuditableEntity
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
       public string CustomName { get; set; }
       public string Model { get; set; }
       public int Serial { get; set; }       
       public bool IsActive { get; set; }
       public string DroneData { get; set; }
       public virtual User User { get; set; }
   }
```

and `user.Drones` always has null value and i can't get and show the data, but this line of validation code

```
if (user.Drones.Contains(drone))
                    return ("This drone has been alredy registred", false);
```

shows me that, the `user.Drones` contains values.
Why i should do, to get `user.Drones` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ef uses a lazy loading, to load child instances you have to use Include

```
var user = context.Users.Where (i=> i.Id==userId)
.Include(i=>i.Drones)
.FirstOrDefault();

//or if you want just drones

var userDrones=context.Users.Where (i=> i.Id==userId)
.Select(i=>i.Drones)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

but it is better to add  a foreign key UserId to Drone explicitly

```
public class Drone : AuditableEntity
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
       .....

      public Guid UserId { get; set; }
       public virtual User User { get; set; }
   }
```

and use this query

```
var userDrones=context.Drones.Where (i=> i.UserId==userId).ToList();
```

Comment: I solved this by using this query `_dbContext.Drones.Where(x => x.User.Id == userId).ToListAsync();`.  I read some docs on microsoft website, and now i know what is lazy loading. Ty for help.